# Square-Cube Digit Usage

Tags: code-golf, math

The point of this challenge is to find the smallest positive integer that uses up *at least* all of the digits supplied in the input after it is squared and cubed.

So, when provided an input such as `0123456789` (i.e. a number that finds the result):

```
69² = 4761
69³ = 328509
```

It means that `69` is the result of such an input. (Fun fact: 69 is the smallest number that uses up all of the decimal digits of 0 to 9 after squaring and cubing.)

### Specification

The input doesn't have to be unique. For example, the input can be `1466` and here's the result:

```
4² = 16
4³ = 64
```

That means we can't just fulfill this input by just doing a number that only uses 1 digit of `6`, it has to have 2 digits of 6 in the output.

### Test cases

Here's an [exhaustive list](https://pastebin.com/6f7PGC2W) of all numbers from 1 to 10000.

```
1333 (or 3133/3313/3331) -> 111
```

### Input specification

- You may take input as a list of digits.
- Since the test cases (somehow) have a bug in it, here's an extra rule: the `0`'s in the input will be ignored.

Comment: I went "Huh?" when I first saw it, but I think I understand.

Comment: Everything before "the point of this challenge" is extremely unclear. Also using 1 as an example input is probably the worst possible choice to make your explanation clear.

Comment: Will the input always be sorted from smallest to largest?

Comment: Can you explain what happens when there are zeros in the input. For example with an input of `50` your list says the output should be `5` which gives us the digits `25 125` which contains no zeros. Does this mean we can ignore zeros in the input? because your example with 69 as an output did not imply that.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I think that list was created with a buggy implementation that didn't check for the square being zero when the cube was zero. My answer doesn't have that issue.

Comment: So what's the answer to the question? can we ignore zeros in the input or not? I note that 69 is the smallest number that works for an input of `123456789` whether the 0 is required or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-æ`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

<s>*Still* very not happy with this!</s> <s>A little happier!</s> *Now* I'm happy!

Takes input as an integer.

```
²+U³s)á dèN
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LeY&code=sitVs3Mp4SBk6E4&input=Mzg)

```
²+U³s)á dèN     :Implicit map of each U in the range [0,input)
²               :U squared
 +              :Concatenate
  U³            :  U cubed
    s           :  Converted to a string (preventing the + from adding the 2 numbers)
     )          :End concatenate
      á         :All permutations
        d       :Any truthy (not 0) when
         è      :  Counting the occurrences of
          N     :    The array of inputs, which is implicitly cast to a string
                :Implicit output of first U to return true
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 13 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

*+1 byte thanks to @Grimmy*

```
∞.Δ23SmJœIÅ?Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8vXNTjIyDc72OTvY83Gof9f@/oZmZiSUA)

---

#### Explanation

```
∞.Δ                  - First number that... 
   23Sm              - Power of 2 and 3 [n^2, n^3] 
       J             - Concatenated
        œ            - Permutations of this number
         IÅ?Z        - any of these start with the number
```

By the way it's quite slow...

Comment: Yup, looks good now!

Comment: Thanks @Grimmy not used the `Å?` much and think I got my `a` and `b` mixed up

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n=1:n*all(f'{n*n}{n**3}'.count(i)>=s.count(i)for i in s)or f(s,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoVgnz9bQKk8rMSdHI029Ok8rrxZIaBnXqusl55fmlWhkatrZFsPZaflFCpkKmXkKxZpAVpoGULu2oeb/gqJMoHSahrqBoZGxiamZuYWluqYmF1zY0MTMDFXA2NgYKPAfAA)

Comment: Ah, very nice use of f-string. Just posted to see you're a few steps ahead! T_T

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>82</s> \$\cdots\$<s>78</s></sup> 77 bytes

Added 2 bytes to fix an error kindly pointed out by [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne).
Switched to Python 2 thanks to [Grimmy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6484/grimmy).
Saved a byte thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```python
f=lambda s,i=1:i*all((`i*i`+`i**3`).count(c)/s.count(c)for c in s)or f(s,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NDoIwEITvPMWmpxbqTymiktSjT@DNmFChxCZYSFsTjfHZcfHgZTPf7M7s@Iq3weXT1Kle36@thsCtEpVNdd9TWtvU1hnOVNZs2QwPF2nDVuEvu8FDA9ZBYKg6iulMsMmr91H3wVTEDRF0IBxO/oGI8pPMocDNHKMJJaIoSzwoGJ9BSokghPjhWuSy2JTb3R7Nco8eqxLQCj@xBEZvXcQqsjjgWnPwZ62UuXAg5jmaJpqWTF8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
1*2,3DFœ&Ƒ@ʋ1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Qy0jH2MXt6GS1YxMdTnUbKv@3ftQwR0HXTuFRw1zrw@1ch9sfNa2J/P8/2lDHRMdMxyxWJ9pAx1AHqAvINwWKmOtY6FgCRQ2BIkAYCwA)

A monadic link taking a list of digits and returning an integer in a single element list.

```
1          ʋ1# | Start with 1 and find the first integer where the following is true, using the input digit list as the right argument:
 *2,3          | - To the power of 2 and 3
     D         | - Convert to lists of decimal digits
      F        | - Flatten
       œ&Ƒ@    | - Check whether the inout digit list is invariant when intersected with this list of digits
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>77</s>  72 bytes

Takes input as a list of digits.

```javascript
f=(a,k)=>([...[k*k]+k**3].sort()+'').match(a.sort().join`.*`)?k:f(a,-~k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctBCsIwEIXhvRdpJk0HpFqwUD1ICDTERtupGWmCS68eW3Cn/Lv38Sb7stEt4zNVga9Dzr4TVhF0Z6ERUZMkU5KUtcHISxJQFgXgwyZ3F/Y74cRj6FH2cKHWr/fqTZAdh8jzgDPfhBd6rw6qUY0B2P1IvfVHTmrruEr@AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                     // f is a recursive function taking:
  a,                      //   a[] = input
  k                       //   k   = counter, initially undefined
) =>                      //
  ( [...[k * k] + k ** 3] // concatenate k² and k³ and split the resulting string
    .sort()               // sort from lowest to highest digit
    + ''                  // coerce back to a string (this puts commas between the
                          // digits, but they are harmless)
  ).match(                // test whether it matches:
    a.sort()              //   the input list sorted the same way  
    .join`.*`             //   joined with .* patterns, so that unused digits and
                          //   commas are ignored
  ) ?                     // if it does:
    k                     //   stop recursion and return k
  :                       // else:
    f(a, -~k)             //   try again with k + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 89 bytes

```
1//.t_/;ContainsNone[Subsets[Join@@IntegerDigits[t^{2,3}],Length@#],Permutations@#]:>t+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwEIDh3acQBBcPQ6x0UJSALopIwbFUSeVIb8gFkutU@uwxm@P/Db@3MqC3Ql@b3SlrpbbyUcdLYLHE6RkY29fYJ5TU3gOxMTcWdBiv5KiYvKcdVHMHD2Qng1l10GD0o5Rl4FT6cJaNXucmEsvSODNp2EMN9bz4UwUaqrLJ@Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>142</s> <s>134</s> 121 bytes

```r
i=1;x=table(scan());l=function(t)x>table(strsplit(paste0(t^2,t^3),"")[[1]])[names(x)];while(any(l(i),is.na(l(i))))i=i+1;i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvRCsIwDEV/RfaUYBHrHkv9kdJBHBUDNY4lYv36OsV7Xg4c7to7Rx9aNLrUAjqTAGKo8fqU2fghYNjO/2irLpUNFlIrR7Dp5Gwa0Q0DpuRzxiR0LwoNc3jdeLuQvKECo2M9CP10G0fe@8Dd78Yv/QM)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>152</s> <s>146</s> <s>144</s> 130 bytes

(This is only if we have to be wrong like your test cases)

```r
i=1;x=scan();x=table(x[x>0]);l=function(t)x>table(strsplit(paste0(t^2,t^3),"")[[1]])[names(x)];while(any(l(i),is.na(l(i))))i=i+1;i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEAC/Ij3tYpFEvYX0IyGFWCIuxLV0txhfH4POaWCYrTXy1lUvS2LALppuJUMNdTIRXfH3nRelF4Ninf5RdJO1kMKaRLMBnc@jzhcchwFDsDFi4PTMAhWjez@oL4k/UIBwJDlx@mmHPB2to3Y9mPYF)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

Uses Arnauld's regex. Takes a list of digits. If that isn't allowed, add 6 bytes to change `d.sort` to `d.chars.sort`.

```ruby
->d,i=0{i+=1until"#{i*i}#{i**3}".chars.sort*''=~/#{d.sort*'.*'}/;i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcvdCoIwGIDh813F0Gi1av7M/lk3UiKWmh@oE7cRIevWV4EnL7wHz2Dub1eJm9tcijWIcISViEynofH8ESjYfym3HnvU@aCYkoOmhIhP4I/FdIwSG5zBulcNTYmfpVYI495ohavrLPtJ2faTb/N@MT9pmcEyRWVXuDCKebLd7Q9HFHHOURKHXw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 28 bytes

```
r0{{2 3}?^im}]mj{j\\z?}j+]fi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBLDoIwFEXnroK5k36gr2/kDlwBODDBBAImQoiJDVMX4BLdSO2HyO3o9Obdnpdel2lo58fS@uHunFjnp5@Ec6rQ6@nSjWsz9q6v69dp7Y/NrfMhWM6e2Yji@/4UUh8CS2AFrBMrilwmNimvgM02z/FCULZQ5sRaBiYQE4gJxARiyuIy5VmsExuYJ5gBL4HXbt6YWwmsgDVwCQxea/b3LQFnrxTxI2wWc2QW@xIsgRVwFnN8iLPYpm61LRHNbKBAwBZkf7EU4eT2Dw)

```
r0       # Range from [0,inf]
{
 {2 3}?^ # {squared, cubed}
 im      # Concatenate
}]m      # Map over each and parse to string
j        # Swap stack
{
 j       # Swap
 \\      # List difference
 z?      # Is null
}
j+]      # Prepend input to make {input j \\ z?}
fi       # Find index s.t.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 70 bytes

```perl
$p=join'.*',sort@F;1while(join'',sort((++$\**2 .$\**3)=~/./g))!~/$p/}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lwDYrPzNPXU9LXac4v6jEwc3asDwjMydVAywMEdTQ0NZWidHSMlLQA1HGmrZ1@nr66ZqainX6KgX6tdX//xsaGxv/yy8oyczPK/6v62uqZ2Bo8F@3wA0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
≔⁰ηＷΦχ›№θＩκ№⁺ＩＸη³×ηηＩκ≦⊕ηＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BDsIgEETvfgXHJcHEhmNPponGgwkHf4DgRogULFD7@bhg9zT7dmbHWJ1M1L7Wc87uFeAkmOXjYbPOI4OL8wUTDESvCXXTU1xDgUWwSecCb85JdaT8mqFDFTcyWsFkuz7cjLlttnv3FA2768/eegsm4Yyh4PPfr5Kjl91MsbHWQUpZj1//Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰η
```

Start at zero.

```
ＷΦχ
```

Repeat until none of the 10 digits satisfies...

```
›№θＩκ№⁺ＩＸη³×ηηＩκ
```

... the count of that digit in the input is greater than the count in the cube and the square...

```
≦⊕η
```

... increment the result.

```
Ｉη
```

Output the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 134 bytes

```c
s,c,i,m;f(n){for(c=s=i=m=1;m;c=(s=++i*i)*i){int a[10]={};for(;c;s/=10)a[c%10]++,s&&a[s%10]++,c/=10;for(m=n;m*a[m%10]--;m/=10);}n=--i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBCoMwEEX3nkIEJTEJ1cbalmFOYrsII5YsEosp3Yhnt0a6dZjN/Pfmk3oRrWuQJK10MDDP52GcGGFAiw5rcEDIAgphS8u3na3/pKarqyfOC0QXCMIJ64qbjvItF0KGojBd@B8U4W469OBK07lIlAK3v8HiUSkLyxqrnbGefUfb82RO0m3e0xYPLMv7h89kOrD6rJtLe73dK87hQGna9hhqrSNc1h8)

Ungolfed and with better variable names:

```c
int square, cube, result, input_copy;

int f(int input)
{
    for(cube = square = result = input_copy = 1;
        input_copy;
        cube = (square = ++result * result) * result)
    {
        int digits[10] = { };
        for(; cube; square /= 10)
        {
            digits[cube % 10]++;

            if(square)
                digits[square % 10]++;

            cube /= 10;
        }
        for(input_copy = input;
            input_copy && digits[input_copy % 10]--;
            input_copy /= 10);
    }
    return result-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 62 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f l=[n|n<-[0..],[]==l\\(show=<<[n^2,n^3])]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcUxDsIgFADQ3VP8EgdNkEBpURPYHL0BpQmDTYnwSwqJi3fH@Ja3@vJ@xdhaSHnbKzx89ewZSj0sEI3FL@qL5Yw5ap0xcZpOZd0@RmuLc09xlu7suo635AOCgbwHrHCE5DMsYImQUhIKRAxK/eeil8Oorrc7ce0H)

Even with the import, Haskell's list difference function `\\` is quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>93</s>  92 bytes

-1 Byte thanks to ceilingcat

```c
D;I;C(N){N=N?C(N/10)+(N%10==D):0;}F(N){for(D=I=0;D<10;C(N)>C(I*I)+C(I*I*I)?D=!++I:++D);I=I;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcuxDoIwEAbgnaeoJCQ9q7G1WIVaGWhIuvQJWAwEwyAYYlwIz14Lk3jL/fnvu2r/qCrntDQyxxZGq2zmw4FRINhGjCqlIaVyKuZr0w9YK6Oo1FdGl49bjs3WAFmWD5lWG0JMSogGaZSRk2u7N3re2w5/@raGYAyQn9fg6waHIkEpiuqyC3eowOzI45M4XxIKIFcuRisXC/EvGGO/gnM@i8l9AQ)

ungolfed:

```c
int D;
int I;

int CNT(N)  // count occurrences of digit D in number N
{
    if (N)
        return CNT(N / 10) + (N % 10 == D);
    return 0;
}

int F(N)
{
    for (D = I = 0; D < 10; ++I)
    {
        for (D = 0; D < 10; ++D)
            if (CNT(N) > CNT(I * I) + CNT(I * I * I))
                break;
    }

    return I-1;
}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat that's clever thanks

Comment: Why do you always have to outgolf me? And how do you do it?